# Rearrange csv rssi data to group by time and location Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, rssi

I have a csv file that is a series of rssi data recordings at different access points over a period of time, of the form:

```
Time     | Signal | Location      
07:37:47 | -98.0  | bedroom             
07:37:47 | -96.0  | bedroom                 
07:37:47 | -91.0  | kitchen             
07:37:47 | -95.0  | kitchen             
07:37:47 | -68.0  | stairs                  
07:37:48 | -60.0  | bedroom  
07:37:48 | -60.0  | stairs              
07:37:48 | -62.0  | stairs   
07:37:48 | -60.0  | kitchen  
07:37:48 | -70.0  | kitchen
```

etc.

And I want to rearrange it to output with the average signal strength for each different location per second to look like this:

```
Time     | bedroom | kitchen  | stairs  
07:37:47 | -97.0   |    -93.0 | -68.0                           
07:37:48 | -60.0   |    -65.0 | -61.0
```

etc.

I.e. I want to move the location of the access point to be a heading of each new column and have the average signal per second in the rows.

Is there a clean way this can be done using pandas? I have been fiddling around with .groupby() and .resample() but can't figure out an easy way of doing it. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at pivot? see [How to Pivot a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to get pivot table and then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to make `Time` regular column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.pivot_table(data=df, values="Signal", index="Time",
               columns="Location", aggfunc=np.mean)\
    .reset_index()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, this reshapes it exactly right however it changes the 'Time' to become an index, how would I keep the time as just a column or is there an extra part I can do to change it back?

Comment: It is possible to `.reset_index()`. I've added it in comment